# How to use the Python debugger in VS code on a remote SSH client

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I'm editing code that is stored on a shared company linux server using VS code on my Windows machine through a remote SSH client. When editing python code natively on Windows, the debugger seems like it is automatically set up once the interpreter is chosen. I'd like to use the same debugger on my remote client code, but I cannot get it to run properly. I have the interpreter pointing to the correct installation on the server as well as the proper hash-bang at the beginning of my program, but I get this error in the terminal:

```
ImportError: libffi.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

as well as a popup error saying "Timed out waiting for launcher to connect" with the option to open the launch.json file. I'm not sure what parameters I should adjust in the launch.json file if any.

Comment: Can you run your program on the server successfully without debugger?

Comment: @YuchenZhong yes I can. I can run the program using the terminal in VS code (I use c shell in this particular instance) without any issue. I can also run all the simple commands on my VM through the ssh client on the terminal in VS code just fine as well. It's only when I try to run and debug (press F5) is when I run into issues